# Can I pass some content via react-router-4's history.push?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How can I pass some info by `react-router-4`'s history push method?

- render a list of users
- when click the user I wanna direct to the new `url` and pass the specific user info
- then render the user base on the passed in  user info

when I think about this, another question came up, if I can pass the user info where does React keep the user's info?

```
<List>
  {users.map(user =>
    <ListItem
      key={user.id}
      thumb={use.img}
      arrow="horizontal"
      onClick={() => this.handleUserClick(user)}
     >
      {user.nickname}
    </ListItem>
  )}
</List>
handleUserClick = (user) => {this.props.history.push(`/user/${user.id}`)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some state with [history's push](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)

```
handleUserClick = (user => {
    this.props.history.push(`/user/${user.id}`, {userName: 'Bob'}); 
})
```

And then you can access the history from your component

```
const User = ({history}) => <span>Hello {history.location.state.userName}</span>
```

This should show "Hello Bob"

Don't abuse this though and prefer to keep the state either in a parent react component or by using a library like redux or mobx if your application gets more complex.

Comment: some more questions. I saw the userName in `props.location.state.userName` as well, is there any different between these two? In this specific usage how can I keep this state in the parent component? I still don't know how to pass this info by `redux`, can u give me a little more info ?

Comment: It's probably the same. As per managing the state, you can start by having a look at this document: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html and this one (first section) https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html. Then you can ask separate questions if you are blocked on new problems.